# Customise CAS Login page adds jsessionid to form action but breaks login

Tags: jsp, cas

I have successfully setup a CAS server for single sign on. Including the comestic stuff such as overriding the bottom.jsp, top.jsp and casLogoutView.jsp templates. My final step is to customise the login page (casLoginView.jsp). However when I do this customisation, the URL in the action attribute of the login form changes from `/login?service=...` to `/login;jsessionid=...?service=...`

This has the affect of the CAS login failing on the first attempt (although there is no error reported) and the login form presented a second time but this time the action attribute doesn't contain the `jsessionid` portion.

Why would this be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I took a closer look at the differences between my jsp template and the default template (by Jasig) and made a stab in the dark: In my template I had changed the `id` attribute in the form to `login`. Changing it back to `fm1` appears to remove the `jsessionid` portion of the url from the `action` attribute.

Go figure.

Comment: This has not fixed my problem of having to attempt login twice! After a day or two the issue return but this time there is no `jsessionid` in the action URL. In fact, every time I restart the service it works for only a limited time...